# defects per team and severity, the defect count is not getting correct

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

This code in my app is not giving correct count of defects, which I can see Quality >> defects, from all defects it shows 1675 defects, but this code returns me only 200 defects.

```
Rally.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define('CustomApp', {
        extend: 'Rally.app.App',
        componentCls: 'app',
        launch: function() {
            Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                model: 'Defect',
                autoLoad: true,
                listeners: {
                    load: this._onDataLoaded,
                    scope: this
                }
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this for paging information](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/guide/data_stores).
By default [Rally.data.wsapi.Store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.wsapi.Store) will only load one page of data. Max page size in Rally is 200. The limit config property specifies the maximum number of records to return. To return all matching records specify a limit of Infinity.

```
var defectStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
    model: 'Defect',
    limit: Infinity    
});
```

Use 2.0rc3 with Rally.data.wsapi.Store instead of older release candidate that has Rally.data.WsapiDataStore

Comment: thanx..I already figured out with some other post regarding this..But I will try to use 2.0rc3 with Rally.data.wsapi.Store, thanx a lot